# Need windows script that moves files based on a string in the file

Tags: windows, batch-file

copy a few hundred plain text, ANSI files based on a keyword or content in a file on a windows server, so i would like to create a .bat file that i can run or schedule.  The files in question all have different keywords in the first line, so i'd like to use that to sort them into different folders.  I had been opening the files individually and moving based on the first line but it's getting tiring!  I tried asking chatgpt for a script and this was the output:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "keyword=SAECH"
set "sourceFolder=C:\Path\To\Source"
set "destinationFolder=C:\Path\To\Destination"
for %%F in (%sourceFolder%\*.txt) do (
set "firstLine="
set /p firstLine=<"%%F"
echo !firstLine! | find /i "%keyword%" >nul && (
   move "%%F" "%destinationFolder%" ))
```

Here is an example of the first line of a file as if i'm searching for the string THIS:

```
    {1:F01XXXXAXXX2190532184}{2:O5352145231127ISAECHNCXXX622XXXXN}
```

"SAECH" is the string that i am looking at and manually moving the file based on the string in the second bracket section. the other data in that bracket changes based on date and time the file was create or sent.  The rest of the information in the file may match but only the string in that second bracket matters.

But there's no output to the source folder.  Is this script just wrong or is there something missing?  I don't know if it's actually looking at the content of the file...  or maybe it can't be done with a basic windows script?

I don't need to change the content of the file or filename, and the original date does not need to be retained.  I just need them copied to a different folder, and i'm fine running the script multiple times and manually changing the search string

tried running the above script but there was no output to the destination folder.

Comment: The first thing you should confirm for us is whether those files are all plain text files, whether they are ANSI or Unicode encoded, and if so which variant. It may also help if you confirm whether they have LF or CRLF line endings. You should also make absolutely sure that we are aware of all possible non alphanumeric characters in the keywords, (you aren't really searching for `test`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  They are plain text, ANSI file.  The files are created automatically.  I couldn't figure out the LF/CRLF, as these files are generated and sent to us.  Yes, there are non-alpha characters.  For example here's part of the first line of the file, as if i'm searching for the string THIS: {1:F01XXXXAXXX2190532184}{2:O5352145231127ITHISNCXXX622XXXXN}    "THIS" is the string that i am looking at and manually moving the file based on the string in the second bracket section.    the other data in that bracket changes based on date and time the file was create or sent

Comment: I would recommend PowerShell rather than cmd.exe shell script (batch).

Comment: The information you've added in response to my comment can make a huge difference to potential responders. Could you please insert that information into your question itself, there is an [Edit] facility available for you to do that. Please also make sure that the example line content is placed into a code box, and that you replace the string `test` with the relevant keyword for that line.

Comment: What is the maximum number of characters on your first lines? When you state that the search 'sub'string is always within the second set of 'braces', do those always begin with incrementing integers, `1:`, `2:`, etc. as shown in your example? Do the lines always begin with space characters, as you have indicated? You also mentioned Windows Server, but did not make clear whether that is being accessed and Scheduled to run from another Windows PC, (and where the source and destination directories are if that is the case), or whether this is all standalone on the one unit.

Comment: The first line is always this format? Same amount of characters and the string to search for is always at the same position? If not, how to identify the relevant string?

Comment: Yes, the first line is always in this format, though there is an additional bracket.  The only relevant information is in the second bracket.  but the numbers would be different message to message as they are a date/timestamp.  If there was a way to just search for the string in the second bracket that would work si

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "searchstrings=SAECH WXYZQ PLUMS"

FOR %%e IN ("%sourcedir%\*.txt") DO (
 rem %%e has filename found
 SET "firstline="
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%y IN ("%%e") DO IF NOT DEFINED firstline (
  rem %%y has contents of first line
  SET "firstline=n"
  FOR %%o IN (%searchstrings%) DO (
   ECHO "%%y"|FIND /i "%%o">NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO MOVE "%%~fe" "%destdir%\whatever %%o \something\"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The difficulty is deciphering quite how the target string is determined. We have a single example, it's not clear whether `this` is involved anywhere and we don't have any clue about uniqueness within the first line or uniqueness of (one of many) target strings in that first line.

So - this solution relies on a target string being uniquely in the first line.

`%%e` is set to the name of each file in turn.

`firstline` is used as a flag and initialised to *nothing* for each file.

The first line is read from the file to `%%y`. `usebackq` tells `for` that the quoted name is a filename, not a string. `delims=` instructs there are no delimiters, so the entire line is assigned to `%%y`.

Since `firstline` is not defined, we process that line. `firstline` is set to a value immediately, so is defined and no further lines will be processed.

`%%o` is set to each target-string in turn. The line in `%%y` is `echo`ed into `find` which looks (`/i`=case-insensitively) for the target-string.

If the target-string is found, `errorlevel` is set to `0`, hence it is not `1 or greater than 1` so the `move` command is `echo`ed to the console.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Comment: Thanks Magoo, unfortunately this doesn't work correctly, it seems that it searching every line in the file not just the first and even when it finds a match it doesn't move it to the new directory.  Both source and destination are in the my documents directory if that helps.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. I suspect you've tried to retype the code and have made a typo. Try cutting and pasting - and use a proper text-editor like `editplus` or `notepad++` (Google - many available free). Note that `notepad` may attempt to reformat the code. Also you need to change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files - `ECHO MOVE` simply shows what the code intends to do so that the action may be verified in case of typos,

Comment: Magoo, you are correct, i definitely fat fingered something.  This time i did use notepad++ and copied directly and it worked like a charm!   This is solved and thanks for your time and effort!